# Why doesn't pstree command show init in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, systemd, init, pstree

I am trying to examine the output from `pstree` command. But for some reason it always starts from something called as `systemd` as opposed to it being init. I have checked to see the process ID's of both init and systemd using `ps aux` command and init has a PID of 1, while systemd has some other PID. So why isn't init being shown in my pstree's output? Is there an option that I need to give?

Also I did read about systemd vs init controversy, but ubuntu 16.04 LTS still uses init to start everything right?

### Update as to why different PIDs?

It turns out that different PIDs that I thought were part of my ignorance. The init had a PID 1, whereas systemd wasn't the thing that I was talking about. Instead when I ran `ps aux|grep systemd`, I found PIDs for `/lib/systemd/systemd-*`, where `*` means some extra characters. So what I was talking about was not systemd, but some other processes that were extensions(is it the correct word?) of systemd I guess.

Some of the examples for that `*` are as follows

```
/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
```

Comment: " ubuntu 16.04 LTS still uses init to start everything right?" Wrong. Systemd **is** init.

Comment: Then why do they have different pids? and why does ps aux command show init as 1 and systemd as something else?

Comment: Try: `readlink -f /proc/1/exe`. Also: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#System_Init_Daemon

Comment: The readlink doesn't output anything. Either way so systemd basically stands for init? Meaning it's an alias for init?

Comment: The other way, init is an alias for systemd. Ok, try `ls -l /sbin/init`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. That totally makes sense now. Post it as an answer so that I can close this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There's still the question of where the different PIDs come from, for which I'll have to wait till I get my hands on a 16.04 system - or you can post what you have understood as an answer, if that's enough

Comment: Oh sorry, I will update my question to include that(I think your answer solved that as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 15.04, init on Ubuntu is systemd. [It is possible to use Upstart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Switching_init_systems), but the default is systemd. For example, `/sbin/init` will be a link to `/lib/systemd/systemd`. `/sbin/{shutdown,reboot,telinit,halt,runlevel,poweroff}` are links to `/sbin/systemctl`. Even in 16.04, Upstart was used as a *session init*, so you might see Upstart as the parent process or an ancestor process in your graphical login (though [it seems to have changed in 16.10](http://news.softpedia.com/news/canonical-to-replace-upstart-with-systemd-for-ubuntu-16-10-s-session-startup-507413.shtml)).

The other processes you see are systemd components; they're developed and distributed along with systemd but many are not essential to running systemd as init. Many components can be replaced or disabled. To quote [the systemd homepage](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/):

> systemd is a suite of basic building blocks for a Linux system. It
>   provides a system and service manager that runs as PID 1 and starts
>   the rest of the system. ...  Other parts include a logging daemon,
>   utilities to control basic system configuration like the hostname,
>   date, locale, maintain a list of logged-in users and running
>   containers and virtual machines, system accounts, runtime directories
>   and settings, and daemons to manage simple network configuration,
>   network time synchronization, log forwarding, and name resolution.

And [this blog post](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/the-biggest-myths.html) from one of the creators of systemd (Lennart Poettering):

> 29. Myth: systemd doesn't allow your to replace its components.
>
>     Not true, you can turn off and replace pretty much any part of
>       systemd, with very few exceptions. And those exceptions (such as
>       journald) generally allow you to run an alternative side by side to
>       it, while cooperating nicely with it.

Comment: I was reading and was going to post the same SystemdForUpstartUsers link. You submitted before I did. I up-voted.

Comment: @D75 Thanks, but you could still post your answer. Maybe it would provide a different perspective.

Comment: You did a great job. No need to write more.