# Ubuntu 16.04 fail to launch the upstart script that works in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 16.04, server, upstart, uwsgi

I know the new Ubuntu is more in favor of `systemd` than the `upstart`, but when I immigrate my website (`python`+`nginx`+`uwsgi`) from the Ubuntu 14.04, the upstart script is failed to launch during the system boot phase.

The upstart script is the same as the [uwsgi docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Upstart.html):

```
# simple uWSGI script

description "uwsgi tiny instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

respawn

exec uwsgi --master --processes 4 --die-on-term --socket :3031 --wsgi-file /var/www/myapp.wsgi
```

I am sure the nginx server is correctly configured, and the command (as follow) in the upstart script can serve the website normally in the shell (I can open the web pages from the browser).

```
uwsgi --master --processes 4 --die-on-term --socket :3031 --wsgi-file /var/www/myapp.wsgi
```

My question is how to make the upstart script work properly in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please modify your text, so that there will be *question*.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a systemd service to `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service`. And disable the upstart script.

Maybe you will need to tweak the service script it a little bit, like the full path, `user` and `After` :

```
[Unit]
Description=uwsgi
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/uwsgi.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/uwsgi --master --processes 4 --die-on-term --socket :3031 --wsgi-file /var/www/myapp.wsgi
User=www-data
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I think the upstart is still supported in 16.04, since the services in `/etc/init` can be loaded at the start-up, but I don't know what I missed.

Comment: It should, but the service is a wrapper for systemd.

Comment: You missed that _since 15.04_ Upstart is not used at the system-wide level by default.  Example: https://askubuntu.com/a/613785/43344  Upstart was still used at the per-user level.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/613814/43344 . But even that was no longer the case as of Ubuntu 16, which you have also missed. See https://askubuntu.com/a/844045/43344 , https://askubuntu.com/a/844502/43344 , and others.